# Amazon Aurora scheduled events

Tags: amazon-aurora

I am running some Amazon Aurora clusters, each with a single read replica.  I allow adhoc queries from certain team members against the read-replica.  Access to the write replica is primarily restricted to the application.
I have created some MySQL events to run daily reports.  I'd like to offload the running of these reports to the read replicas.  Can this be achieved natively within Aurora, or would I have to do this externally, explicitly going through the read replica?

Many thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event scheduler is enabled per instance using instance parameters [1], and I believe you've already done this. However, you cannot force a scheduled event to be executed only on your replica as far as I know. Depending on what your use case is, a better alternative would be to write a Cloudwatch Event [2] that calls into your cluster RO endpoint and executes the query you want to schedule.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Reference.html#AuroraMySQL.Reference.ParameterGroups

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge Np! Is there anything else you'd like as part of this post?

Comment: Hi Karthik - my reputation's too low to upvote (publicly viewable).  Thanks